# Receive email notifications in android app

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

Im trying to make a simple app (just for learning sake) that will be able to send and receive emails from my own server. I don't have a problem sending emails from my app, my problem is:

1. How do you receive push notifications from the email server
2. Have the app check inbox, refresh the inbox list

I have tried searching for this, but have found nothing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C2DM does push notifications, depending on your server. Search stackoverflow for it.

The app can check the inbox with whatever API is available to get the server's status. Even HTTP is possible.

The SampleSyncAdapter sample app is an example of using a sync adapter to regularly synchronize data between the server and the device, but you can use the same idea for download-only.